# Perl. Send signal: Invalid argument

Tags: perl

I have a program,I know its pid and  it has a signal processing:

```
 $SIG {INT} = sub {.... };
```

I have tried to send a signal from another program

```
my $pid = 5396;
kill 2, $pid or die $!;
```

and got an error "Invalid argument at ..."! 
I have tried to write

```
kill "INT",$pid or die $!;
kill "INT"=>$pid or die $!;
```

etc. but still have this error. 
Why?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Works for me. What's in the handler?

Comment: "What's in the handler?" Do you mean $SIG {INT} = sub {.... }; or something else?

Comment: Yes, the signal handler.

Comment: Nothing special, just  $SIG{INT}  = sub { $keep_going = 0; say "INT";}; When I use command line and  press Ctrl+C all works fine: I see "INT" and programm ends. But "kill 2, $pid or die $!;" doesn't work, I see "Invalid argument" and main programm is still running...

Comment: Looking at the `kill` entry in `perldoc perlport` it seems to me that you cannot do such a thing on Windows.

Answer (score 1):

From [perldoc -f kill](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/kill.html)

```
kill SIGNAL, LIST
kill SIGNAL
        Sends a signal to a list of processes. Returns the number of
        processes successfully signaled (which is not necessarily the
        same as the number actually killed).
```

The error is misleading. The `kill` function returns the number of processes successfully signalled, which is this case is probably zero `0`. It does not have any valid information about why it failed, so it sets `$!` to a rather generic message.

If I were to guess, I would say that your `$pid` is incorrect. I get the same error when testing with non-existent pids. It does contain a number, though, because if you do not supply a number, you get this error:

```
Can't kill a non-numeric process ID at ...
```

Comment: But I use realy pid of running program and I can find process with such pid in task manager. Why it can be incorrect?

Comment: I actually get the same problem with that signal in Windows, so perhaps it is related to the OS.

Answer (score 1):

Windows doesn't have signals. That's a unix thing. However, Perl does try to emulate them a little.

- `kill INT => $pid` results in `GenerateConsoleCtrlEvent(CTRL_C_EVENT, pid)`
- `kill BREAK => $pid` results in `GenerateConsoleCtrlEvent(CTRL_BREAK_EVENT, pid)`
- `kill TERM => $pid` results in `GenerateConsoleCtrlEvent(CTRL_BREAK_EVENT, pid)`
- `kill KILL => $pid` results in `TerminateProcess(process_handle, sig)`

[`GenerateConsoleCtrlEvent`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683155%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) can only signal "a console process group that shares the console associated with the calling process", so it won't work unless the process to which you are trying to send the signal has a console and it's the same one as your Perl process.

You are getting that error because the process to which you are trying to send a signal doesn't have a console, and doesn't share the same console as the script sending the signal.